# Intersections in PGFplots

Tags: pgfplots, intersections

I can get intersections to work in TikZ, but not PGF plots. I defined a command to show the intersections to make sure that it is identical in both cases. Commenting out the `\ShowIntersection` line in the 2nd graph results in a syntax error.  Is there a different way to name the curves in PGF plots?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

% Define this as a command to ensure that it is same in both cases
\newcommand*{\ShowIntersection}{
\fill 
    [name intersections={of=GraphCurve and HorizontalLine, name=i, total=\t}] 
    [red, opacity=1, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}] 
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt)
        node [above left] {\s}};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=GraphCurve, mark=none, domain=-2.5:2.5, thick]%
    plot ({\x},{\x*\x});%

\draw [red, thick, name path=HorizontalLine] 
    (-2.5,3) -- (2.5,3);%

\ShowIntersection% Works fine here
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[name path=GraphCurve, mark=none, domain=-2.5:2.5, thick]%
    ({x},{x*x});%

\addplot [red, thick, name path=HorizontalLine] 
    coordinates{(-2.5,3) (2.5,3)};%

%\ShowIntersection% Error: Do not know path "GraphCurve" 

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Each plot is drawn in its own scope, so the named paths won't be known outside the `\addplot` command. In this case, you should use the `name path global` option instead of `name path`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\ShowIntersection}{
\fill 
    [name intersections={of=GraphCurve and HorizontalLine, name=i, total=\t}] 
    [red, opacity=1, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}] 
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt)
        node [above left] {\s}};
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[name path global=GraphCurve, mark=none, domain=-2.5:2.5, thick]%
    ({x},{x*x});%

\addplot [red, thick, name path global=HorizontalLine] 
    coordinates{(-2.5,3) (2.5,3)};%

\ShowIntersection% Works

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: intersections of plots in pgfplots]

Note that `name path global` creates problems if there are paths with the same name in the document (even if they are in different `tikzpicture` environments), some intersections will be found several times. I would recommend to assign unique names to the paths, and adapt the `\ShowIntersection` macro to take the names of the paths as arguments:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

% Define this as a command to ensure that it is same in both cases
\newcommand*{\ShowIntersection}[2]{
\fill 
    [name intersections={of=#1 and #2, name=i, total=\t}] 
    [red, opacity=1, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}] 
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt)
        node [above left] {\s}};
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[name path global=a, mark=none, domain=-2.5:2.5, thick]%
    ({x},{x*x});%

\addplot [red, thick, name path global=b] 
    coordinates{(-2.5,3) (2.5,3)};%

\ShowIntersection{a}{b}

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=c, mark=none, domain=-2.5:2.5, thick]%
    plot ({\x},{\x*\x});%

\draw [red, thick, name path=d] 
    (-2.5,3) -- (2.5,3);%

\ShowIntersection{c}{d}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thankt Jake, this works great. However, this brings up the question [if there is a way to clear these global path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21421/is-there-a-way-to-clear-paths-previously-defined-with-name-path-global-in-tikz)