# Add variable tick in axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

Consider the following code where I detect the crossing of a function to a given threshold.
I am plotting the line from the intersection to the x-axis, and storing the intersection in `\p1`

I would like to add a second axis environment identical to the first one with only an additional tick at `\x1`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    clip=true,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    grid = major,
        grid style={dashed},
    xmin=1,
    xmax=64,
    samples =32,
    ymax = 1.6,
    ymin  = -0.2,
    xlabel={\emph{sample number}},
    xlabel style={at={(1,-0.1)}, anchor=south},
    legend cell align=left,
    legend pos=outer north east,
  ]
\addplot[name path global=one,blue,mark=+,domain=1:64] {exp(-log10(2)/(8^2/4)*(\x-32)^2)};
\addplot[name path global=two,red,domain=1:64] {0.5};
\path [name intersections={of=one and two, name=i}];
\path let \p1=($(i-1)$) in (\x1,\y1);
\draw[dashed] (i-1) -- ($(axis cs:0,-0.2)!(i-1)!(axis cs:64,-.2)$);

\legend{Sampled signal,Threshold}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    clip=true,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=64,
    samples =32,
    ymax = 1.6,
    ymin  = -0.2,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={\x1},
    extra x tick labels={$t_{step}$},
  ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

My attempt to use `\x1` directly in the axis environment is failing.

[image]

Comment: The content of `\x1` is only available within the context of the `let` command, so you'll need to store it in a global macro to access it later on. However, I doubt that that will be of much use, since `\x1` is in "paper units", not "data units", so you can't simply feed it to `extra x tick`. Do you actually want a second axis (i.e. are you going to add plots to that axis), or do you simply want to label the x position of the intersection?

Comment: @Jake no I just want to add an extra tick to the axis at the given position `\x1`. But I would like it to have the same style than the axis. I figure adding an other axis would be the simplest solution. Is there no way to cast \x1 into "data units"?

Comment: @vrleboss Why don't you just solve `exp(-log10(2)/(8^2/4)*(\x-32)^2) == 0.5` by hand? It might be not portable, but sometimes you have to lower your sights relating to automation.

Comment: @HenriMenke unfortunately I will add random noise to the curve after. I need something automated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you converted your code into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that a simple cut and paste is enough to get started.

Comment: @PeterGrill done. To obtain the output shown comment out the second  `axis` definition.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I did something similar along the lines of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88386/plot-functions-and-their-point-of-intersection

Comment: @percusse unfortunately, your solution does not draw the tick. And everything is done manually. I am looking for a way to somehow have an `extra x ticks={\x1}` after the end of the axis. It does seem complicated but that's why I added the reward :)

Comment: Actually the most helpfull answer I found during my search was this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118436/adding-extra-ticks-inside-the-axis-environment. Red reply to it's own post gave me the idea for the second `axis` environment, but I got stuck there as well.

Comment: It doesn't draw the tick but does the same thing. The question was not to draw the tick but get the position so you can add the tick.

Comment: @percusse: I don't understand your last reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solves the problem but using two `axis` environments.

[image]

Or if you want the number value of the tick just comment the `extra x tick labels={$t_{step}$},` line.

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={font=\small}}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\makeatletter
\def\markxof#1{
    \pgf@process{#1}
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgfplotsunitxlength+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x}
}
\makeatother

\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={%
    clip=true,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xmin=1, xmax=64,
    samples =32,
    ymax = 1.6, ymin  = -0.2}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        mystyle,
        grid = major,
        grid style={dashed},
        xlabel={\emph{sample number}},
        xlabel style={at={(1,-0.2)}, anchor=south},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend pos=outer north east
    ]
        \addplot[name path global=one,blue,mark=+,domain=1:64] {exp(-log10(2)/(8^2/4)*(\x-32)^2)};
        \addplot[name path global=two,red,domain=1:64] {0.5};
        \path [name intersections={of=one and two, name=i}];
        \pgfplotsextra{
            \path (i-1) \pgfextra{\markxof{i-1}\xdef\mytick{\pgfmathresult}};
        }
        \path let \p1=($(i-1)$) in (\x1,\y1);
        \draw[dashed] (i-1) -- ($(axis cs:0,-0.2)!(i-1)!(axis cs:64,-.2)$);
        \legend{Sampled signal,Threshold}
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
        mystyle,
        xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
        extra x ticks={\mytick},
        extra x tick labels={$t_{step}$},
        extra x tick style={
            xticklabel style={yshift=-10}
        }
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! I think a way using only one `axis` environment would be  to store the curves in global path without plotting them. Finding the intersections of the paths and saving it in `mytick`. Then define the axis env. Then plot the global paths.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve a similar result as desired by placing a `node [below]`  the x-intercept based on the computed intersection:

[image]

The above version does not have the `x tick` mark at the x-intercept as I think it works better.
However, if uncomment the `\draw` in the `pgfonlayer` environment you obtain the tick:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer} 
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground layer}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    clip=true,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    grid = major,
    grid style={dashed},
    xmin=1,
    xmax=64,
    samples =32,
    ymax = 1.6,
    ymin  = -0.2,
    xlabel={\emph{sample number}},
    xlabel style={at={(1,-0.1)}, anchor=south},
    legend cell align=left,
    legend pos=outer north east,
  ]
\addplot[name path global=one,blue,mark=+,domain=1:64] {exp(-log10(2)/(8^2/4)*(\x-32)^2)};
\addplot[name path global=two,red,domain=1:64] {0.5};
\path [name intersections={of=one and two, name=i}];
\path let \p1=($(i-1)$) in (\x1,\y1);

\coordinate (XIntercept) at ($(axis cs:0,-0.2)!(i-1)!(axis cs:64,-0.2)$);
\draw[dashed] (i-1) -- (XIntercept);


\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground layer} 
    %\draw [gray,very thin] (XIntercept) -- ++(0,-2.25pt);
    \node [below, rotate=90, anchor=east,] at (XIntercept) {$t_{step}$};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\legend{Sampled signal,Threshold}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a valid answer but not the one I am looking for. I am looking for a way to modify the `axis` based on my plot. I had the node option also but wasn't satisfied with it.