# yticklabels Problems

Tags: pgfplots, labels, ticks

I'm going to draw a certain function from a .txt file. I'd like to specify/to highlight a point of that function on the function itself by a marker and a label.

Moreover, I'd like to put a notch on the x-axis and a label.

Can you suggest the code needed to carry it out?

Thank you!!!

What is following is the code I wrote.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape, 8pt]{book}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz, siunitx, pgfplots, relsize, pgfmath}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, pgfplots.units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{change x base,
            x SI prefix=milli,
            change y base,
            y SI prefix=micro
            }

\pgfplotsset{
every axis/.append style = {
font=\relsize{1},
% riguarda le tick labels
line width = 1pt,
% oppure: thin, semithick, thick,
% very thick
tick style = {line width = 1pt}
},
every axis x label/.append style = {
font = \relsize{2}
},
every axis y label/.append style = {
font = \relsize{2},
rotate = -90
%xshift = -0.7em,
%yshift = -1.4em
},
major grid style = {
line width = 0.5pt,
gray,
%dash pattern = on 4pt off 4pt
},
every axis title/.append style = {
font = \relsize{1}
},
legend style={at={(850e-3, 700e-3)},anchor=north, line width=1pt}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
    [   axis background/.style={fill=gray!15},
        %axis x line=bottom,
        %axis y line=left,
        xmin=-0.3, xmax=0.3,
        ymin=-0.000004, ymax=0.000004,
        x unit=V,
        %x unit prefix=m,
        y unit=A,
        %y unit prefix=u,
        minor x tick num = 1,
        minor y tick num = 1,
        width=12cm, height=9cm,
        grid=major,
        %xtick = {-0.3,-0.2,...,0.3},
        %ytick = {-0.000004,-0.000003,...,0.000004},
        xlabel = {$V_d$},
        ylabel=$I_{d_1}-I_{d_2}$
    ]
\addplot [thick, green!100] file {diffecorrenti.txt};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add to your question a simple test file `diffecorrenti.txt` so your example becomes quickly compilable for everyone.

Comment: I'm sorry. The file could not be easy to handle because of the fact that it is very "heavy". I'll try to post two photos so that everyone can understand the problem.

Comment: @leoleoleo: Instead of posting pictures, it would be much better if you could reduce the code to make it self-contained: Remove all the lines that don't have anything to do with your question (`\usepackage{etex}`, for example, or `font=\relsize{1}` and so on) and include some dummy data.

Comment: The problem is very similar to this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129571/add-variable-tick-in-axis?rq=1..... BUT I have got a txt and not a math function. THANKS a lot.

Comment: @leoleoleo Then make a much shorter data file and post that in the example. Beyond that, how do you want the point selected: "highlight the point nearest (or at) x=k", "highlight the k-th point", ...?

Comment: @leoleoleo I've provided an answer below. Is something like that what you want? By the way, when I asked you to add a simple test file `diffecorrenti.txt` to your question, I didn0t mean the actual file, but a simple dummy file like the one in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility; for this example I used the following simple file `diffecorrenti.txt`:

```
1 2
3 -3
4 5
6 7
```

and suppressed parts of the original code that were not relevant to the question and to the solution.

[image]

1. For the first requirement, you can use the `axis cs` coordinate system to place a `\node` with some predefined style at the desired location at one point in your graph. In the example I did this in two ways:

   - Using a simple `\node` in the shape of a filled circle and used the `label` key to place the label.
   - Using a `\node` and a `pin` to add the label.
2. For the second requirement, you can use the `extra x ticks` (and perhaps also `extra x tick labels`) to add additional tick positions and tick labels to the x axis.

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{
every pin/.style={
  fill=orange!20,
  font=\footnotesize
  },
small dot/.style={
  fill=orange!70!black,
  circle,
  scale=0.5,
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   axis background/.style={fill=gray!15},
  minor x tick num = 1,
  minor y tick num = 1,
  width=12cm, 
  height=9cm,
  grid=major,
  xlabel = {$V_d$},
  ylabel=$I_{d_1}-I_{d_2}$,
  extra x ticks={1.2,4.7},
  extra x tick labels={extra1,extra2},
  extra x tick style={
    grid=none,
    font=\footnotesize\color{red},
    tick label style={rotate=90}
  }
]
\addplot [thick, green] file {diffecorrenti.txt};
\node[small dot,label=left:{$(4,5)$}] at (axis cs:4,5) {};
\node[small dot,pin=30:{$(3,-3)$}] at (axis cs:3,-3) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try your solution. The second requirement could be ok... For the first one I have some doubts because You've supposed to know the exactly position of that points. For example, (4,5) is on your list. In my case, the coordinates of the point, could not be on the list. (They could be situated between two consecutives other points. What do you think about this? Could it be a problem? Thank you again!