# Coordinates of an Intersection, outside of the axis-environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, axis

I would like to access the x- and y-Coordinate of an intersection, outside of the axis environment. This is what I believed would solve my problem, based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18389/tikz-node-at-same-x-coordinate-as-another-node-but-specified-y-coordinate) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129571/add-variable-tick-in-axis):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%[xmin=0,xmax=1]
\addplot [color=blue, mark=none,domain=0:1, name path global=blau] {x};
\addplot [color=red, mark=none,domain=0:1, name path global=rot] {1-x};
\path [name intersections={of=blau and rot,by=inter}];
\path let \p1=(inter) in node[] () at (\x1,\y1);
\end{axis}

\node[color=black] () at (\x1, 0) {Access Demonstration x};
\node[color=black] () at (0, \y1) {Access Demonstration y};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load intersections and no, this method won't work since `\x1` and `\y1` are not known where you want to use them. However, there is an even simpler way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%[xmin=0,xmax=1]
\addplot [color=blue, mark=none,domain=0:1, name path global=blau] {x};
\addplot [color=red, mark=none,domain=0:1, name path global=rot] {1-x};
\path [name intersections={of=blau and rot,by=inter}];

\end{axis}

\node[color=black] () at (inter|-0,0) {Access Demonstration x};
\node[color=black] () at (inter-|0,0) {Access Demonstration y};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So what is the \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} about?

Comment: @HiwiMakro It sets the version to be 1.16.