# \pgfmathprintnumber and pre-defined styles

Tags: pgfkeys, pgfmath

In text mode I would like to use `\pgfmathprintnumber` to print numbers in an uniform style. The style used shall be defined in the preamble of the document. See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
   textnumber/.style={
     fixed,
     use comma,
     fixed zerofill,
     precision=4,
     1000 sep={.},
     },
  }

\begin{document}
  The deviation from the origin is \pgfmathprintnumber[textnumber]{10.008}\,\%.
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this gives me the following error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/textnumber'
and I am goinf to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I am a little bit confused now and don not know where else to put the definition of the `textnumber`style. Do you have a hint for me?

Comment: Why don't you consider `siunitx`?

Comment: Is there any significant difference between using `siunitx`and the way I use `pgfmathprintnumber`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\pgfplotsset` sets the prefix `/pgfplots/` for the keys and `\pgfmathprintnumbers` uses the prefix `/pgf/number format/`.

So your definition of `textnumber` needs the explizit prefix `/pgf/number format/`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
   /pgf/number format/textnumber/.style={
     fixed,
     use comma,
     fixed zerofill,
     precision=4,
     1000 sep={.},
     },
  }

\begin{document}
  The deviation from the origin is \pgfmathprintnumber[textnumber]{10.008}\,\%.
\end{document}
```

or you have to use `\pgfmathprintnumber[/pgfplots/textnumber]{...}` and prefix all your options for `textnumber` with `/pgf/number format/`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
   textnumber/.style={
     /pgf/number format/.cd,% <- changes the prefix for the following options
     fixed,
     use comma,
     fixed zerofill,
     precision=4,
     1000 sep={.},
     },
  }

\begin{document}
  The deviation from the origin is \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgfplots/textnumber]{10.008}\,\%.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Update**

As @percusse mentioned in a comment you could also use `\pgfkeys` instead `\pgfplotsset`. Then you need at least the packages `pgfkeys`, `pgfmaths` and `pgfcore` for your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfmath,pgfcore}% or pgf or tikz or pgfplots

\pgfkeys{
   /pgf/number format/textnumber/.style={
     fixed,
     use comma,
     fixed zerofill,
     precision=4,
     1000 sep={.},
     },
  }

\begin{document}
  The deviation from the origin is \pgfmathprintnumber[textnumber]{10.008}\,\%.
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfmath,pgfcore}

\pgfkeys{
   /textnumber/.style={
     /pgf/number format/.cd,% <- changes the prefix for the following options
     fixed,
     use comma,
     fixed zerofill,
     precision=4,
     1000 sep={.},
     },
  }

\begin{document}
  The deviation from the origin is \pgfmathprintnumber[/textnumber]{10.008}\,\%.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pgfkeys` might be more appropriate if there is no pgfplots key is set.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for some command like this because `pgfplotsset` only works when the `pgfplots` package is loaded... (however, I am using the `pgfplots` package in my document so this wasn't a problem for me.)
But just for the record: Using `\pgfkeys` instead of `pgfplotsset` in the above example is a more general way to define the style?

Comment: Yes, `\pgfkeys` and `\pgfmathprintnumber` already work in your example if you load at least the packages `pgfkeys`, `pgfmath` and `pgfcore` (or one of the packages `pgf`, `tikz`, `pgfplots`).  I have updated my answer.