# Stacking plots in animation using fill between library (with dynamic calculation of intersection segments?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, animations, intersections

As a followup question to [Filling the area under a graph based on intersection with another graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180046/filling-the-area-under-a-graph-based-on-intersection-with-another-graph), I'm looking to create the following effect:

- Fill based on the coordinates of the intersection between the two graphs.
- Plots stacked, so area under the `normal`-curve, but between the two graphs (under `normal` but above `skew`) should be `cyan!20`. The area under the other curve should be `green!20`.
- None of those graphical anomalies... problem is though, that the first intersection of the graph disappears within the animation and the `intersection segments` key is completely static (it will *always* use the n-th intersection of the n-th path, bugger!).

I've fiddled around with the `domain` key, but I'm getting very underwhelming results. :-(

The intended result I can only reproduce at specific points, not for the entire animation:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gvvNzc4.png?1]

Christian Feuersänger suspects a bug, so I've moved the original animation code downward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{animate}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{normal}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{erf}{1}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathparse{#1 > 0 ? 1 : -1}%
    \edef\sign{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{abs(#1)}%
    \edef\x{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(1+0.3275911*\x)}%
    \edef\t{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{%
      1 - (((((1.061405429*\t -1.453152027)*\t) + 1.421413741)*\t 
      -0.284496736)*\t + 0.254829592)*\t*exp(-(\x*\x))}%
    \edef\y{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{(\sign)*\y}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{skew}{3}{%
        \pgfmathparse{(exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*(#2)^2))*((erf((#3*(x-#1))/(sqrt(2)*#2)))+1))/(sqrt(2*pi)*#2)}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      hide y axis,
      axis lines*=center, 
      axis on top,
      no markers, 
      domain=-1:18, 
      samples=20,
      xlabel=\empty, 
      ylabel=\empty,
      every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
      every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
      height=5cm, width=12cm,
      xmin = -1, xmax=18,
      xtick=, ytick=\empty,
      enlargelimits=false, 
      clip=false
  ]
  \addplot [name path=normal,very thick,cyan!85!black!50] {normal(10,3.416969)};
  \addplot [name path=skew,very thick,red!85!black!50] {skew(1,4,10)};
  \path [name path=lower, name intersections={of=skew and normal}, intersection segments={of=skew and normal,sequence=B1 -- A2}];
  \path[name path=axis]
(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
  \addplot [draw=green!80,fill=green!20] fill between [of=lower and axis, soft clip={(intersection-2) rectangle (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0)}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

---

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{animate}
%\usepackage{fp}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{normal}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{erf}{1}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathparse{#1 > 0 ? 1 : -1}%
    \edef\sign{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{abs(#1)}%
    \edef\x{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(1+0.3275911*\x)}%
    \edef\t{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{%
      1 - (((((1.061405429*\t -1.453152027)*\t) + 1.421413741)*\t 
      -0.284496736)*\t + 0.254829592)*\t*exp(-(\x*\x))}%
    \edef\y{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{(\sign)*\y}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{skew}{3}{%
        \pgfmathparse{(exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*(#2)^2))*((erf((#3*(x-#1))/(sqrt(2)*#2)))+1))/(sqrt(2*pi)*#2)}%
}
\newcommand*{\power}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      hide y axis,
      axis lines*=center, 
      axis on top,
      no markers, 
      domain=-1:18, 
      samples=20,
      xlabel=\empty, 
      ylabel=\empty,
      every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
      every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
      height=5cm, width=12cm,
      xmin = -1, xmax=18,
      xtick=, ytick=\empty,
      enlargelimits=false, 
      clip=false
  ]
  \addplot [name path=normal,very thick,cyan!85!black!50] {normal(0.125*#1,3.416969)};
  \addplot [name path=skew,very thick,red!85!black!50] {skew(1,4,10)};
  \path [name path=lower, name intersections={of=skew and normal}, intersection segments={of=skew and normal,sequence=B1 -- A2}];
  \path[name path=axis]
(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
  \addplot [draw=cyan!80,fill=cyan!20, stack plots=y] fill between [of=normal and skew,domain=(intersection-2):\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}] ;
  \addplot [draw=green!80,fill=green!20, stack plots=y] fill between [of=lower and axis, soft clip={(intersection-2) rectangle (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0)}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop,palindrome]{32}
  \multiframe{94}{ik=32+1}{
    \power{\ik}
    }
    \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That could be a bug in the `intersections` lib. Can you reduce the example to something without animation? If it is a bug, it should show up in the results of either `name intersections`, `intersection segments` or `fill between` - all rely on the same sub-routine.

Comment: Note: `stack plots=y` is unsupported for `\addplot fill between`.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I have updated my question/request post with the code without any animations in it. You can move around the graph `normal` between values of the first argument between 10 and 11 (any value will do - I have set `normal(10,3.416969)` in the example code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a bug in the `intersections` library of tikz which becomes evident once we show all intersection nodes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{normal}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{erf}{1}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathparse{#1 > 0 ? 1 : -1}%
    \edef\sign{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{abs(#1)}%
    \edef\x{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(1+0.3275911*\x)}%
    \edef\t{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{%
      1 - (((((1.061405429*\t -1.453152027)*\t) + 1.421413741)*\t 
      -0.284496736)*\t + 0.254829592)*\t*exp(-(\x*\x))}%
    \edef\y{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{(\sign)*\y}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{skew}{3}{%
        \pgfmathparse{(exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*(#2)^2))*((erf((#3*(x-#1))/(sqrt(2)*#2)))+1))/(sqrt(2*pi)*#2)}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      hide y axis,
      axis lines*=center, 
      axis on top,
      no markers, 
      domain=-1:18, 
      samples=20,
      xlabel=\empty, 
      ylabel=\empty,
      every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
      every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
      height=5cm, width=12cm,
      xmin = -1, xmax=18,
      xtick=, ytick=\empty,
      enlargelimits=false, 
      clip=false
  ]
  \addplot [name path=normal,very thick,cyan!85!black!50] {normal(10,3.416969)};
  \addplot [name path=skew,very thick,red!85!black!50] {skew(1,4,10)};
  \path [name intersections={of=skew and normal},font=\tiny] 
    node[draw] at (intersection-1) {1/\pgfintersectionsolutions} 
    node[draw] at (intersection-2) {2/\pgfintersectionsolutions}
    node[draw] at (intersection-3) {3/\pgfintersectionsolutions}
  ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Apparently, the node 1/3 should not be there at all.

Unfortunately, that makes it hard to find a suitable workaround: if you modify your code such that it uses node 3 instead of 2, your example will fail to compile as soon as you receive a new version of TikZ which contains the fix.

Comment: Thanks for investigating. :-) I'll be waiting for the next version of TikZ then, I guess.

Comment: Would it be possible to choose, e.g., whichever intersection point is farthest right, regardless of how many intersection points are computed?

Comment: Good idea, @CharlesStaats. I arrived at a suitable solution which always relies on the last intersection, but some frames of the animation still failed to produce the expected output. I will look into it. Anyway, this question lead to some improvements already, so future versions will become easier for related tasks.