# How to fill color the interval in a curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
no markers, 
domain=0:6, 
samples=100,
ymin=0,
axis lines*=left, 
%xlabel=$x$,
every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
height=5cm, 
width=12cm,
xtick=\empty, 
ytick=\empty,
enlargelimits=false, 
clip=false, 
axis on top,
grid = major,
hide y axis
]

\addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(x, 3, 1)};

\pgfmathsetmacro\valueA{gauss(1,3,1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueB{gauss(2,3,1)}

\draw [gray] (axis cs:3,0) -- (axis cs:3,0.4)
 (axis cs:4.2,0) -- (axis cs:4.2,0.19);



\node[below] at (axis cs:4.2, 0)  {$1.2$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:3, 0)  {$0$}; 
\end{axis}



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want to fill color the interval $0 \leq z \leq 1.2 $, how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165666/32374

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83503/fill-the-area-determined-by-two-pgfplots-graphs . Would you agree?

Comment: No, it is not duplicate. I want to get a simpler answer. [link] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83503/fill-the-area-determined-by-two-pgfplots-graphs) here, they metioned about  intersection of two curves. This question is different. @percusse

Comment: I see but you can intersect the curve with the verticals for that purpose no? That's what the answer of Christian does. But in anycase you can draw the curve twice, once full domain and once filled but limited domain on top.

Comment: You are absolutely right. However, my LateX skill isn't enough to adapt the  answer of Christian to my LateX source. @percusse

Comment: @percusse Christian's answer is for version 1.10, but this question uses 1.8, so he'll have to use Jake's answer I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For up to the version 1.10, you can add the following code just before your curve cyan plot (not after, for optimal clipping):

```
\addplot[
    fill=cyan!50,
    draw=none,
    domain=3:4.2,
    ] {gauss(x,3,1)} \closedcycle;
]
```

[image]