# Using fancyhdr to create an image based header and footer

Tags: graphics, header-footer, fancyhdr, sweave, r

I'm trying to generate a latex report (via Sweave and R) where the header of the document is an image that covers everything (including the top/left/right page margin) and the footer covers everything (including the bottom/left/right page margin) such that the graphics for header and footer are flush to the page edges.

Kind of like this:

[image]

I've been playing around with `fancyhdr` but I can't seem to get it to do anything but stick out in the middle of the page. Additionally, I can't seem to get the header/footer to show up on ALL pages.

Help would be appreciated, here's where I am so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure} 
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\lhead{\includegraphics{documenthead.jpg}}
\lfoot{{\includegraphics{footer.jpg}}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\title{Example Document}
\author{Author Name}
\date {\today}
\maketitle
\section{This is a good example}
Example text goes here \\
Repeat me to force a new page \\ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: check out: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fancy-chapter-headings/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a better solution using the [`wallpaper` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper), replacing foo and bar produces the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{wallpaper}

\begin{document}
\ULCornerWallPaper{1}{foo}
\LLCornerWallPaper{1}{bar}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect for what I wanted - thank you!

Comment: Is there a simple way of putting say ULCornerWallPaper on odd pages, and URCornerWallPaper on even?

Answer (score 11):

If you are not stuck on using `fancyhdr`, you could adapt the solution from [How do I add an image in the upper, left-hand corner using TikZ and graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38751/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-the-upper-left-hand-corner-using-tikz-and-graphicx/38754#38754)
which uses [the `background` package](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/background/):

[image]

### Notes:

- Need at least two runs to see the images.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{background}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyGraphicLogo}{% For imported graphic logo
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=4cm]{foo}};
  \node at (current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=4cm]{bar}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\SetBgContents{\MyGraphicLogo}% Select included image

\SetBgPosition{current page.north west}% Select location
\SetBgOpacity{1.0}% Select opacity
\SetBgAngle{0.0}% Select roation of logo
\SetBgScale{1.0}% Select scale factor of logo

\begin{document}
\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-16]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, this seems to get close to what I'm looking for. Could you help me in understanding where I utilize the names of the images. Would it be a simple matter of replacing `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: Actually, I figured that part out. Although I'm having problems with the positioning of the image. It seems to be that `{current page.north west}` puts the image in the top right but it is centered with the horizontal midpoint of the image is at the top edge of the page.

Comment: Yes `foo` and `bar` are the files names options to `\includegraphics`. You also need to remove the `[demo]` option when loading the `graphicx` package. Also, in my example I had used `current page.north`, but you can still use `current page.north west` and include `[anchor=west]` if you want the image to be on the top left hand side.

Comment: I had some problems with using the `background` package to place things on pages containing only floats.

Comment: @tohecz: If that is not already a question on that issue it would be helpful to post one with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Off the top of my head I don't understand why that would be the case.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I would like to be helpful on that, but I was in quite hurry and used the `watermark` package, moreover it was in a very complicated situation.

Comment: @tohecz: Understood. When you get a chance please try to create a small example with just floats. I had started with the `watermark` package as well and forgot why I switched to `background`.  Although, have to admit that there appears to be some strange interaction with `background` and the `tikz intersections` library related to [pgf error no shape named i 0 is known but only upon 2nd run](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42071/pgf-error-no-shape-named-i-0-is-known-but-only-upon-2nd-run).  But since there is other strangeness in that case, it is probably not the fault of `background`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the command you are looking for is `\fancyhfoffset`. The left side seems needs to increase by `\oddsidemargin + \hoffset + 1in` and the right side needs to increase by `\evensidemargin + \marginparwidth - \marginparsep` (this is surprising to me I thought it would have been plus `\marginparsep`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\hrulefill{}}%
    \fancyhead[R]{\hrulefill{}}%
    \fancyfoot[L]{\hrulefill{}}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}

\fancyhfoffset[L]{\oddsidemargin + \hoffset + 1in}
\fancyhfoffset[R]{\evensidemargin + \marginparwidth - \marginparsep}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
First page

\clearpage

Second page
\end{document}
```