# margins and text position

Tags: header-footer, margins

When answering this question: [Using fancyhdr to create an image based header and footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42073/using-fancyhdr-to-create-an-image-based-header-and-footer/42237#42237)

I needed to get the distance from the left edge of the paper to the beginning of `\textwidth` and the distance from the end of `\textwidth` to the right edge of the paper. For the distance from the left edge I used `\oddsidemargin + \hoffset + 1in` to adjust `\headwidth` via `\fancyhfoffset` and it put the start of the header on the left edge of the paper. For the distance from the right edge, I thought it was `\evensidemargin + \marginparwidth + \marginparsep`, but this resulted in the header overshooting the right edge of the page. It appears the correct distance is `\evensidemargin + \marginparwidth - \marginparsep`.

I think I am missing something about how `\marginparsep` (or some other page "margin") works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\hrulefill{}}%
    \fancyhead[R]{\hrulefill{}}%
    \fancyfoot[L]{\hrulefill{}}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}

\fancyhfoffset[L]{\oddsidemargin + \hoffset + 1in}
\fancyhfoffset[R]{\evensidemargin + \marginparwidth - \marginparsep}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
First page

\clearpage

Second page
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `layout` package gives you a graphical display and listing of your current layout parameters:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}

\layout

\end{document}
```

shows

[image]

Does that help?

Comment: It shows the problem. Is the distance between the right edge of the margin notes and the edge of the paper `\evensidemargin` or is it just some unnamed leftover space?