# Can I put a logo in the header using memoir?

Tags: graphics, header-footer, memoir

Part of our corporate standard is to place a small logo graphic at the top right of each page. It looks like `fancyhdr` handles this quite easily, but I'm using the `memoir` class, and it doesn't seem to be compatible with `fancyhdr`.

Comment: Duplicate: [Place a TikZ picture on every page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41382/place-a-tikz-picture-on-every-page), or [Using fancyhdr to create an image based header and footer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42073/using-fancyhdr-to-create-an-image-based-header-and-footer/).  You should be able to replace the `tikzpicture` with an `\includegraphics` to insert an existing image, as illustrated in as answer to at the second link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `memoir` features (See Secion 7 **Pagination and headers** of the manual), you can define your page style to include the logo in the desired position. A litlle example

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% demo option just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\thepage}{}{\includegraphics[height=15pt]{
logo}}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{\includegraphics[height=15pt]{
logo}}{}{\thepage}

\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```