# How can I add a logo to a page header in Lyx?

Tags: graphics, positioning, header-footer, lyx

I am writing a thesis and want to add the university logo accross the top of my first page. I have a banner.pdf file, which will fit nicely accross the top of the page. But how do I go about placing this image in the header of the first page with Lyx??

Much like the graphic shown in this question
[Using fancyhdr to create an image based header and footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42073/using-fancyhdr-to-create-an-image-based-header-and-footer/)

But I only want to do this in the header for the first page.

If it matters I want to generate A4 pages and my document type is AMS article.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38751/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-the-upper-left-hand-corner-using-tikz-and-graphicx/ helps?

Comment: Could you explain what you have tried? Does putting `\includegraphics{banner}` in the appropriate place not work? (With the `graphicx` package loaded)