# Different image in every page's footer

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer

I found 
[Using fancyhdr to create an image based header and footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42073/using-fancyhdr-to-create-an-image-based-header-and-footer)
which is helpful and gave some ideas but I want to basically put in the bottom right or center of the footer a different image file (pdf or jpg) for each page in a latex document.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

P.S. Sorry, I typically use article class with lots of mathtools in latex or xelatex, but I am very flexible!

Comment: Name your image file as `image-1.png`, `image-2.jpg`, etc and input them via `\includegraphics{image-\arabic{page}}`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As **JLDiaz** mentioned in his comment, you can name your images `image-1.png`, `image-2.png`, etc. and then use the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package to include them using

```
\includegraphics[<options>]{image-\arabic{page}}
```

from the `graphicx` package. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\setlength\footskip{40pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{\includegraphics[height=30pt]{image-\arabic{page}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-23]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another possibility, using this time the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[bottom]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgContents{\includegraphics[height=30pt]{onebit-\arabic{page}}}
\SetBgVshift{40pt}
\SetBgOpacity{1}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-23]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Make sure to have as least as much images as the number of pages in your document.

After a comment, the idea is to have the images to the right, on the footer, but outside the text area; this can be accomplished, in the `fancyhdr` example, using `\fancyfootoffset`; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\setlength\footskip{40pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{\includegraphics[height=30pt]{image-\arabic{page}}}
\fancyfootoffset[R]{4cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-23]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `background` approach, one can use `\SetBgHshift{<length>}`.

Comment: @Medina Well it worked, but I was wanting to place it in the far right corner and the option [R] only places it on the right of the footer. The cite I quoted had the image all the way across. Similarly, is it possible to place these figures even right of the typical footer?

Comment: @nate please see the last example in my updated answer.