# set minimum number of pages for TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am looking for a method to set the *minimum* number of pages for the TOC.

For example, with the MWE, chapter 1 starts on the 3rd page in first run, and the 14th page on second run.  Knowing this I would like to get the first run to also start chapter 1 on the 14th page by inserting a sufficient number of blank pages for the TOC.  In the second run, there should be 0 pages inserted (at least in this case since I reserved the correct number of pages).

### Background:

This bug is causing me quite a bit of grief: ["pgf Error: No shape named i-0 is known", but only upon 2nd run](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42071/pgf-error-no-shape-named-i-0-is-known-but-only-upon-2nd-run).
The problem seems to be related to
the number of pages used by the TOC changing between runs.
So was hoping that something like this can be used as a temporary fix until the bug in the `intersections` library is fixed.

### Code:

```
\def\NumberOfChapters{10}
\def\NumberOfSections{50}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\clearpage

\mainmatter
\foreach \x in {1,...,\NumberOfChapters}{
    \chapter{Chapter \x}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\NumberOfSections}{
        \section{Section \y}
        \lipsum[1-7]
    }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps add `\foreach\x in {\value{page},...,14}{\vbox{}\newpage}`?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: That does it. If you use `\tableofcontents\cleardoublepage \foreach\x in {\value{page},...,14}{\vbox{}\newpage} \pagenumbering{arabic}` the chapters are set "in place." Note that using `\pagenumbering` resets the page value to 1, so it should be issued *after* the "magic formula."

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch (and Werner): You guys are geniuses!! Yes, this solves this problem and the one that has the bounty. If you guys want to post that as a solution to these two questions, you'll get the bounty. (Joseph deserves some credit too but not sure if a bounty can be split).

Comment: @Werner go for it. I'm too busy with physics to write more than a two-line answer, which would be a real shame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Bruno's suggestion, the following works, setting Chapter 1 on (absolute) page 14, regardless of the compilation:

```
\def\NumberOfChapters{10}
\def\NumberOfSections{50}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
\cleardoublepage

\foreach\x in {\value{page},...,14}{\vbox{}\newpage}% Insert up to absolute page #14.

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\mainmatter
\foreach \x in {1,...,\NumberOfChapters}{
    \chapter{Chapter \x}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\NumberOfSections}{
        \section{Section \y}
        \lipsum[1-7]
    }
}
\end{document}
```

Note that using `\pagenumbering` resets the page value to 1, so it should be issued *after* the "magic formula."

Comment: The solution to this also provides a work around for [pgf error no shape named i 0 is known but only upon 2nd run](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42071/pgf-error-no-shape-named-i-0-is-known-but-only-upon-2nd-run). Do you want to post something there so you can get the bounty (half if I can figure out hot to split it between this workaround solution and Joseph's response)?

Comment: @PeterGrill: I've added an answer to the linked post; thanks. As I mentioned to @cmhughes a little while back: "We should develop a rep-sharing program." `:)`

Comment: Yeah, would be nice to be able to split the bounty between you and Joseph but from what I read up on last night it does not look like I can do that.  Testing solution now...