# Tikz -- Rotating a line around an intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I've been trying to rotate a line around an intersection. The problem (I think) is that the intersection is in a previous scope (I need that to have the correct clipping), and the new scope doesn't know what (intersection-1) is. I've been trying the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (0,0) circle (5);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip [name path=clipA] (0,0) -- (-30:25) -- (-150:25) -- cycle;
        \fill[name path=SpeciesA, blue, line cap = round] (-0.2,0) -- (-0.2,-4) -- (0.2,-4) --  node[sloped, below] {Species A} (0.2,0) -- cycle;
        \tikz\name intersections={of=clipA and SpeciesA}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip [(0,0) -- (-30:25) -- (90:25) -- cycle;
        \fill[blue!60!red, line cap = round, rotate around={150:(intersection-1)}] 
        (-0.2,0) -- node[rotate= 150, sloped, below] {Species C} (-0.2,-3) -- (0.2, -3) -- (0.2, 0) -- cycle; 
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0) -- (-150:25) -- (90:25) -- cycle;
        \fill[blue!60!green, line cap = round, rotate=210] (-0.2,0) -- (-0.2,-3) -- (0.2, -3) --  node[rotate= 210, sloped, below] {Species B} (0.2, 0) -- cycle ; 
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As I say, LaTeX doesn't seem to know what (intersection-1) is, once we get there. Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Similar Question: [Intersections in PGFplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/intersections-in-pgfplots).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `name path global` instead of `name path` to make the paths available for finding the intersections in a different scope. Note that you shouldn't use `name intersection` like a macro with `\tikz`, but instead use it as an option in a `\path` command (or similar).

As percusse pointed out, instead of using `name path global` you can also find the intersection within the scope where the lines are named, by using `path[name intersections={of=clipA and SpeciesA}];`. The intersections are nodes, so they are available globally (even in other `tikzpicture`s!) as `intersection-1`, `intersection-2`, and so on.

[image]

### References:

- One might also want to have a look at [Is there a way to clear paths previously defined with name path global in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21421/is-there-a-way-to-clear-paths-previously-defined-with-name-path-global-in-tikz).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (0,0) circle (5);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip [name path global=clipA] (0,0) -- (-30:25) -- (-150:25) -- cycle;
        \fill[name path global=SpeciesA, blue, line cap = round] (-0.2,0) -- (-0.2,-4) -- (0.2,-4) --  node[sloped, below] {Species A} (0.2,0) -- cycle;
    %    \tikz        \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0) -- (-30:25) -- (90:25) -- cycle;
        \fill[name intersections={of=clipA and SpeciesA},blue!60!red, line cap = round, rotate around={150:(intersection-1)}] 
        (-0.2,0) -- node[rotate= 150, sloped, below] {Species C} (-0.2,-3) -- (0.2, -3) -- (0.2, 0) -- cycle; 
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0) -- (-150:25) -- (90:25) -- cycle;
        \fill[blue!60!green, line cap = round, rotate=210] (-0.2,0) -- (-0.2,-3) -- (0.2, -3) --  node[rotate= 210, sloped, below] {Species B} (0.2, 0) -- cycle ; 
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've replaced the problematic line with `\path[name intersections={of=clipA and SpeciesA}];` and removed the third clip and it also works similarly.

Comment: @percusse: Ah yes, you're right, you can find the intersection within the scope where the paths are named, the `intersection-1` node will automatically be available globally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I needed to know. The path[name intersections...] syntax was elluding me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to stackexchange. How do I mod this answer up? Apparently I can't, but I wouldn't want to breach the netiquette by not giving positive feedback.

Comment: @ManoloMartínez: You should be able to click on the upward pointing arrow next to the answer to upvote it, and there should be tick mark next to the answer that you can click to accept it.

Comment: An alternative (haven't tested it, though) would be to locate the intersection(s) inside the scope where the paths are named and label them with coordinates to make them global.  Then only the coordinates are global, not the paths.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Isn't that basically what percusse suggested? As I understand it, using `\path [name intersections...]` creates coordinates for all the intersections, which are then global (since they're just nodes).

Comment: @AndrewStacey Like Jake wrote, there is nothing to do because the nodes are defined globally. The original code is fine with some corrections.

Comment: Oh, sorry!  I looked more closely at the code than the text.  My apologies.

Answer (score 8):

Yes `(intersection-1)` is known,  but there are two problems in your code. If you remove them, your code compiles  fine.

1) `\tikz\name intersections={of=clipA and SpeciesA}` ? why `\tikz` here and `\name` ? ??

2) `\clip [(0,0) -- (-30:25) -- (90:25) -- cycle;`  why  the [( ?

The next code compiles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (0,0) circle (5);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip [name path=clipA] (0,0) -- (-30:25) -- (-150:25) -- cycle;
        \fill[name path=SpeciesA, blue, line cap = round] 
        (-0.2,0) -- (-0.2,-4) -- (0.2,-4) --  node[sloped, below] {Species A} (0.2,0) -- cycle;
        \path[name intersections={of=clipA and SpeciesA}];
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0) -- (-30:25) -- (90:25) -- cycle;
        \fill[blue!60!red, line cap = round, rotate around={150:(intersection-1)}] 
        (-0.2,0) -- node[rotate= 150, sloped, below] {Species C} (-0.2,-3) -- (0.2, -3) -- (0.2, 0) -- cycle; 
    \end{scope}    
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0) -- (-150:25) -- (90:25) -- cycle;
        \fill[blue!60!green, line cap = round, rotate=210] 
        (-0.2,0) -- (-0.2,-3) -- (0.2, -3) --  node[rotate= 210, sloped, below] {Species B} (0.2, 0) -- cycle ; 
    \end{scope}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```