# How to specify a name path for the axis in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, intersections

When I use the {axis} environment, the axis are drawn automatically so I am not able to specify a name for them? I would like to be able to compute intersections with the axis as in [Intersections in PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/intersections-in-pgfplots). Is there a way for me to specify a name for these axis?

One solution would be for me to *redraw* the axis with `draw=none` and then specify a name for that path, but am wondering if there is a better way.  Something like `xaxis name path=` would be ideal?

There is a `every axis` key, but so perhaps I could append it to that, but then how would I specify a different name for the x-axis and y-axis?

**Update** The intent of my question was to find intersections with the lines `x=0` and `y=0` (not the boxed borders that get drawn automatically). Here is a MWE attempt:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Linear Axis Style/.style={
        clip=true,
        minor tick num=0,
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis on top=true,
        x axis line style={name path=XAxisLine},
        y axis line style={name path=YAxisLine}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\ShowIntersection}[2]{
\fill 
    [name intersections={of=#1 and #2, name=i, total=\t}] 
    [red, opacity=1, every node/.style={black, opacity=1}] 
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt)
        node [above right] {\s}};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Linear Axis Style,
    xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
    ymin=-1, ymax=3,
    ]

\addplot[name path global=a, mark=none, domain=-2.5:2.5, thick]%
    ({x},{x*x-0.5});%

%\ShowIntersection{a}{XAxisLine}% Do not work
%\ShowIntersection{a}{YAxisLine}

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to use the `axis` option `x axis line style={name path=<name>}` (you don't need to use `name path global` in this case, as the axes are drawn in the same scope as all other graphical objects):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\ShowIntersection}[2]{
\fill 
    [name intersections={of=#1 and #2, name=i, total=\t}] 
    [red, opacity=1, every node/.style={black, opacity=1}] 
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt)
        node [above right] {\s}};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
    ymin=1, ymax=3,
    x axis line style={name path=AxisLine}]

\addplot[name path global=a, mark=none, domain=-2.5:2.5, thick]%
    ({x},{x*x});%
\ShowIntersection{a}{AxisLine}

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: x axis line style=name path]

This is not quite ideal, however: This finds the intersections with all borders, not just the x axis. This is because by default, the border is drawn using just one path. Note also that if you would use `axis line style` instead of `x axis line style`, the intersections would be found twice because `axis line style` applies its options to `x axis line style` and `y axis line style`, which are then in turn both applied to the border path, so you end up with two `name path global` options.

To fix the problem, one might try to use the option `separate axis lines`. In this case, `x axis line style={name path=<name>}` has to be changed to `x axis line style={every path/.style={name path=<name>}}` because the options are passed to a scope instead of a path.

Unfortunately, in our example no intersections would be found. This is because with `separate axis lines`, the bottom and top axis lines are drawn in that order, using two different paths but the same options. Only the top axis (or the right axis in case of y axes) ends up being assigned the `name`.

One way around this would be to use the options

```
axis lines=left,
x axis line style={every path/.style={name path=AxisLine}}
```

This will only draw the left and bottom axis, leading to

[image: axis lines=left]

This might be good enough for your application. If you do require a boxed plot and the ability to find the intersections with only the bottom x axis, you will have to patch the code in the file `pgfplots.code.tex`.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my question: I meant intersections with the lines `x=0` and `y=0`, not the borders. Have provided a MWE adapted from your example.

Comment: @Peter: This is because you added the new option `axis on top`, which means that the axis will be drawn at the very end, after you've called `\ShowIntersections`. If you move `\ShowIntersections` outside the `axis` environment and use `name path global` instead of `name path`, it finds the intersections but for some weird reason draws the points with an offset. If you remove `axis on top`, everything works, but for some reason `axis y line=middle` leads to intersections with the y axis being found twice. I'll have to look into why that is.

Comment: I am trying to manually draw the lines and need access to the values of `xmin`, `xmax`, etc. Have posted a follow up question [on how to access xmin xmax, ymin, ymax from within PGFplots axis environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22018/how-to-access-xmin-xmax-ymin-ymax-from-within-pgfplots-axis-environment).

Comment: @Peter Grill: I've posted an answer to that, but the problem with the intersection being found twice still appears. I investigated a bit more, and it turns out that this problem is caused by the fact that one of the points of the plot lies exactly on the y axis. If you set the domain to something slightly asymmetric, everything works fine.

Comment: Yep, I see the same behavior.This seems like a bug then?  Adding a slight asymmetry to the xaxis works, but there does appear to be a minimum asymmetry required, below which it still shows as two points.