# pgfplots: How to add the origin to the axis in a robust way?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

### Question

I add the origin to my graph with

```
after end axis/.code={\path (axis cs:0,0) node [anchor=north west,yshift=-0.075cm] {0} node [anchor=south east,xshift=-0.075cm] {0};}
```

(code found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39099/8323)).
This works fine is the origin is on my axis. 
But, there are problems if `0` is not in the values taken by `y` (see the pictures below).

> Is there a way to fix this issue?
>
> By this, I mean an option that would
>   display the origin only when needed.

### Pictures

#### first picture

[image]

#### second picture

I cannot put it here, but it prints two pages!!!
[image]

### Code

#### first code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[grid = major, 
clip = true, 
clip mode=individual, 
axis x line = middle, 
axis y line = middle, 
xlabel={$x$}, 
xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west}, 
ylabel={$y$}, 
ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south}, 
domain = 2:5, 
xmin = 2, 
xmax = 5, 
enlarge y limits={rel=0.13}, 
enlarge x limits={rel=0.07}, 
restrict y to domain=1:2,
ymin = 1, 
ymax = 2, 
after end axis/.code={\path (axis cs:0,0) node [anchor=north west,yshift=-0.075cm] {0} node [anchor=south east,xshift=-0.075cm] {0};}]

\addplot[color=Gold3, samples=1000, smooth, ultra thick, unbounded coords=jump, no markers] gnuplot{atan(x)-1/2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### second code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[grid = major, 
clip = true, 
clip mode=individual, 
axis x line = middle, 
axis y line = middle, 
xlabel={$x$}, 
xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west}, 
ylabel={$y$}, 
ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south}, 
domain = 2:5, 
xmin = 2, 
xmax = 5, 
enlarge y limits={rel=0.13}, 
enlarge x limits={rel=0.07}, 
%restrict y to domain=1:2,
%ymin = 1, 
%ymax = 2, 
after end axis/.code={\path (axis cs:0,0) node [anchor=north west,yshift=-0.075cm] {0} node [anchor=south east,xshift=-0.075cm] {0};}]

\addplot[color=Gold3, samples=1000, smooth, ultra thick, unbounded coords=jump, no markers] gnuplot{atan(x)-1/2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You most likely want to use `rel axis cs` instead of `axis cs` to set the origin.

Comment: You can use the `axis description` coordinate system instead: `after end axis/.code={
  \node[left=2pt] at (axis description cs:0,0) {0};
  \node[below=2pt] at (axis description cs:0,0) {0};
  }`

Comment: Hi! Both solution work and don't work, in a sense. The origin is displayed in a good way, but since `0` is out the range, the origin in this case should not be displayed.

Comment: Some remarks: I don't know why (and what is the loss in this trick), but the behavior is better with `before` than with `after`. More precisely, `before end axis/.code={\path (axis cs:0,0) 
node [anchor=north west,yshift=-0.075cm] {0} 
node [anchor=south east,xshift=-0.075cm] {0}
;}` is better.

Comment: @Colas: Probably better due to the fact that with `before end axis` you are still within the `axis` environment so that `pgf` can determine if that text is within the bounds of the plot, but `after end axis` `pgf` is unable to make that determination.

Comment: What @PeterGrill said. And also if you have two axis in the `middle` why would you want zero as the tick label?

Comment: this could be a bug: I believe `clip mode=individual` does not apply the clip path to paths like your node...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `axis direction cs` as in

```
\path (axis direction cs:0,0) node [anchor=north west,yshift=-0.65cm,xshift=-0.7cm] {0} node [anchor=south east,xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.7cm] {0};}]
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[grid = major,
clip = true,
clip mode=individual,
axis x line = middle,
axis y line = middle,
xlabel={$x$},
xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
ylabel={$y$},
ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
domain = 2:5,
xmin = 2,
xmax = 5,
enlarge y limits={rel=0.13},
enlarge x limits={rel=0.07},
restrict y to domain=1:2,
ymin = 1,
ymax = 2,
after end axis/.code={\path (axis direction cs:0,0) node [anchor=north west,yshift=-0.65cm,xshift=-0.7cm] {0} node [anchor=south east,xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.7cm] {0};}]

\addplot[color=Gold3, samples=1000, smooth, ultra thick, unbounded coords=jump, no markers] gnuplot{atan(x)-1/2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

there is also `axis description cs` which you may like to exploit for this purpose.

```
after end axis/.code={\path (axis description cs:0,0) node [anchor=north west,yshift=-0.075cm,xshift=-0.2cm] {0} node [anchor=south east,xshift=-0.075cm,yshift=-0.2cm] {0};}]
```

However for this particular graph, `(0,0)` position is completely wrong as seen in the picture.