# Changing arrowheads size in pgfplots axes

Tags: pgfplots, arrows

I need to change the default axes arrowheads size of pgfplots when using the option `axis lines=center`. Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5472), I tried this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{myaxis} = [decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[ultra thick]{latex'}}},
                      postaction={decorate}, shorten >=0.4, line width=0.02pt];
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center, axis line style={myaxis}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but it doesn't work as I would expect, since the axes lines aren't drawn at all.

Could you help me?
Thanks,

Luigi

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Customising axis lines is a bit unintuitive: For one, the `decoration` to be used in the `postaction` needs to be specified *within* the `postaction`. And applying a `postaction` to the axes when using `axis lines=left` (instead of `axis lines=middle`, for example) requires the use of the `every path/.style` (similar to what was done in [How to specify a name path for the axis in PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21740/how-to-specify-a-name-path-for-the-axis-in-pgfplots/21761#21761)). To avoid an infinite recursion in this case, you need to clear the `postaction` once it's been executed for the first time. This can be done using the `nomorepostaction` key described in [Applying a postaction to every path in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/applying-a-postaction-to-every-path-in-tikz/5354#5354).

Here's your axis generated using

```
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={my axis}
]
\addplot coordinates {(-0.1,-0.2) (1.2,1.2)};
\end{axis}
```

[image]

And here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    nomorepostaction/.code=\makeatletter\let\tikz@postactions\pgfutil@empty, % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/applying-a-postaction-to-every-path-in-tikz/5354#5354
    my axis/.style={
        postaction={
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position 1 with {
                    \arrow[ultra thick]{latex}
                }
            },
            decorate,
            nomorepostaction
        },
        thin,
        -, % switch off other arrow tips
        every path/.append style=my axis % this is necessary so it works both with "axis lines=left" and "axis lines=middle"
    }
}
\makeatother


\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={my axis}
]
\addplot coordinates {(-0.1,-0.2) (1.2,1.2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It was what I asked for till I learnt to edit the arrowhead style by myself.

Comment: @Liverpool: Pleasure. Editing the arrowhead style is certainly an option, but I'm not sure it's a better approach per se. With the `decoration`, you're a lot more flexible: you can change the arrow type without having to declare a new arrowhead, you could use a different colour for the tip, and you can set the size just as well by using `line width=<size>`.

Comment: you're right, but if you need an open arrowhead, it could be difficult to estimate how much to shorten the line such that it doesn't cut the tip. It all started by this question on the Italian users' TeX group (http://www.guitex.org/home/it/forum/5-tex-e-latex/72725-dimensione-arrows-in-tikz)

Comment: I did the trick by using the arrows.meta library (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182788/arrow-style-with-arrows-meta-library ). For example `y axis line style={-{Latex[length=3mm,width=2mm]}}`. Hope it helps too.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this solution and I think it's better for me. I edited the definition of the latex' arrowhead so that you can specify directly the tip length or use the default value (8pt). So the arrowhead size is now no more dependent on the line width. Obviously you can use the same solution in plain TikZ.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{mylatex'}{mylatex'}
{
  \newdimen\len
  \len=\pgfgetarrowoptions{mylatex'}
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-0.4\len}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{0.6\len}
}
{
  \newdimen\len
  \len=\pgfgetarrowoptions{mylatex'}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.6\len}{0\len}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{0.35\len}{0.05\len}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-0.1\len}{0.15\len}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-0.4\len}{0.375\len}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{-0.15\len}{0.1\len}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-0.15\len}{-0.1\len}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-0.4\len}{-0.375\len}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{-0.1\len}{-0.15\len}}
  {\pgfqpoint{0.35\len}{-0.05\len}}
  {\pgfqpoint{0.6\len}{0\len}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}
\pgfsetarrowoptions{mylatex'}{8pt}
\pgfkeys{/tiplen/.default=8pt, /tiplen/.code={\pgfsetarrowoptions{mylatex'}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=left, axis line style={-mylatex'}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, axis line style={-mylatex', /tiplen=4pt}]
\addplot [only marks] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.5)};
\draw [-mylatex', /tiplen=1cm] (axis cs: 0.1,0.1) -- (axis cs: 0.4,0.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm adding a comment just to highlight that more arrows are now available [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80090/13482).

Answer (score 3):

TikZ 3.0.0 or higher has introduced arrows.meta which allows a lot of manipulation on arrows. If you're ok with changing the arrow head style a bit, you can get a much simpler code using arrows.meta:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis lines=center, axis line style={-{Stealth[scale=3]}}]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following output:

[image: pgfplots axes with larger arrow head]

Note: Stealth is the closest arrowhead to the default axis arrow head in pgfplots, latex'. Unfortunately there is no arrows.meta version of the old latex' yet. Latex is also a good option.

Note 2: For details on what can you manipulate, see [Ch. 16 of the TikZ manual](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#section.16).