# Adjusting arrow style on pgfplots axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows

Using `axis line=middle` in pgfplots creates arrow tips on the end of the axes.  How can I adjust the size, style, etc?  I suppose one way would be to make axes without arrows (using `axis line*=middle`) and then make the arrows separately using a  `\draw` command, but I'm wondering whether there are options one can pass to the `\begin{axis}...\end{axis}` that will do the trick.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51584/3954.

Comment: `every y axis line`, `every inner/boxed/non boxed axis line` etc. there are gazilllion options in the manual. Without a simple example it is difficult to guess your use case.

Answer (score 4):

Try having a look at page 193 of the [pgfplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). Give the following a try:

```
every inner x axis line/.append style={|->>},
```