# arrow style with arrows.meta library

Tags: tikz-arrows

I'm ready to style arrows using `arrows.meta` library, though I haven't found any documentation with predefined arrow styles syntax. The only one I know is `Stealth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black,step=1cm,thin] (0,0) grid (6,6);
\draw[-{>[scale=1.3,red,length=5mm,width=2mm]]},semithick] (0,1) -- (6,1);
\draw[-{Stealth[scale=1.3]},semithick] (0,1) -- (6,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm seeking for `angle 45` or `angle 60` arrow tips used in `arrows.meta`.

Comment: Can anybody help me? I would be grateful also for recommending another arrow library for individual satisfactory arrow styling...

Comment: What am I doing wrong I can't find any single documentation for arrows.meta???

Comment: PGF manual Section 16.5 ?

Comment: An abstract from PGF Manual: http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/_discuss/thread/d0a57d64/3f8b/attachment/pgfmanual%20-%20new%20section.pdf

Comment: @ferahfeza That's Luigi's version if I'm not mistaken not the official version. Also [see Luigi's answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5461/3235)

Answer (score 18):

Here is a demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black,step=1cm,thin] (0,0) grid (6,6);
\draw[-{Latex[red,length=5mm,width=2mm]},semithick] (0,1) -- (6,1);
\draw[-{Latex[red,length=5mm,width=2mm,angle'=90]},semithick] (0,1) -- (5,1);
\draw[-{Latex[red,length=5mm,width=2mm,angle'=45,open]},semithick] (0,1) -- (4,1);
\draw[-{Latex[red,length=5mm,width=2mm, angle=60:10pt]},semithick] (0,1) -- (3,1);
\draw[-{Stealth[scale=1.3,angle'=45]},semithick] (0,2) -- (6,2);
\draw[-{Stealth[scale=1.3,angle'=90]},semithick] (0,2) -- (5,2);
\draw[-{Stealth[scale=1.3,angle'=45,open]},semithick] (0,2) -- (4,2);
\draw[-{Stealth[scale=1.3,inset=1pt, angle=90:10pt]},semithick] (0,2) -- (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For customising arrows, refer to (entire) section 16 of `pgfmanual` (`texdoc pgfmanual` from terminal/command prompt)