# Scaling arrows.meta with tranform shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{myarr/.style={
        -{Triangle[width=6pt, length=9pt]},
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[myarr] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[draw, anchor=west]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
    \draw[myarr] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[draw, anchor=west]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Is it possible to define the `myarr` style so that the arrows will scale when the `transform shape` key is given with a `scale`?

Notice that in the real case the arrow will be drawn deep in the code, so I would like a solution where I just change the definition of `myarr`, without touching the rest of code. Something like defining a `\scaledpt` that enable doing

```latex
\tikzset{myarr/.style={
        -{Triangle[width=6\scaledpt, length=9\scaledpt]},
}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use `\pgflowlevelsynccm`. However, it is to be used with great care.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{myarr/.style={
        -{Triangle[width=6pt, length=9pt]},
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[myarr] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[draw, anchor=west]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
    \pgflowlevelsynccm
    \draw[myarr] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[draw, anchor=west]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more complex but less dangerous solution is to read out `\pgfgettransformentries` and scale the arrow dimensions accordingly. As requested in the comment, it is spelled out here.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{myarr/.style={%
/utils/exec=\pgfgettransformentries{\tmpa}{\tmpb}{\tmpc}{\tmpd}{\tmp}{\tmp}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mydet}{\tmpa*\tmpd-\tmpb*\tmpc},
        -{Triangle[width=6pt, length=9pt,scale={sqrt(abs(\mydet))}]},
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[myarr] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[draw, anchor=west]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
    \draw[myarr] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[draw, anchor=west]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments on the background. The Euclidean transformations in 2 dimensions are given my a transformation matrix (with entries `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, say) and a translation, i.e. a 2d vector. As explained on p. 1142 of the pgfmanual v3.1.4, they can be inferred with `\pgfgettransformentries`. The key `scale=<factor>` sets `a=<factor>` and `d=<factor>`, but in general the 2d volume gets scaled by the determinant `a*d-b*c` (such that under orthogonal transformations it is invariant) and the scale factor is its square root. (The determinant is just the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), and has been used e.g. before e.g. in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86897/138900) and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496418). I was urged to mention these earlier posts, which I am happy to do, but where should one stop?) That is, the second proposal does *not* tilt the arrow, but the [first one does that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432172) yet is more "dangerous". A third option would be to apply `\pgflowlevelsynccm` only to the arrow, yet this will be quite a hack.

Let me also mention that the pgf manual is very clear on that line widths do *not* get transformed with `scale=<factor>`, regardless of whether or not you add `transform shape`. And (standard) arrows do scale with the line width. From this it is obvious that `transform shape` should not transform the size of arrow heads. If you want to have a fully rescaled picture, you'd need to scale the line widths, too. This can be fed into the arrows as well.

Comment: Yes, that's viable, but... 1) t also scales the arrow and the nodes even if `transform shape` is not here, which shouldn't (arguably) happen, and 2) it would be nice to restrict it to the arrowheads.

Comment: @Rmano I spelled out the second option. As I said, you can read out the transformations with `\pgfgettransformentries` and infer the scale transformation from that. This transformation is a matrix, but for your purpose the square root of its determinant is the scale factor. These tricks have been used elsewhere to adjust the line widths automatically.

Comment: @Rmano You're welcome! I made it a bit more fool proof by taking the absolute value, such that there is no problem in connection with, say, `xscale=-1`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat yes, I too had thought about the absolute value thing --- I have used it in https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/275 (yep, I linked to this answer, for everybody peace of mind).

Comment: I have removed a series of comments here related to the mathematical basis of the calculation. To summarise: the use of a Jacobian determinant approach is seen in various answers on the site but is not unique to any of them: it is a common mathematical approach.

Answer (score 8):

How about `transform canvas`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{myarr/.style={
        -{Triangle[width=6pt, length=9pt]},
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[myarr] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[draw, anchor=west]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.5}]
\draw[myarr] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[draw, anchor=west]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Rmano: You are not going to find the simplest solution, right? ^^

Comment: This is in principle a very neat solution if it were not for the fact that `transform canvas` screws up the bounding box.

Answer (score 7):

The arrows have the `scale`, `scale length` and `scale width` option *(see page 193 of the TikZ 3.1.4b manual)*.
I have changed your style so that this factor becomes a parameter of your style.

```
\tikzset{myarr/.style={
        -{Triangle[width=6pt, length=9pt,scale=#1]},
        myarr/.default=1
}}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{myarr/.style={
        -{Triangle[width=6pt, length=9pt,scale=#1]},
        myarr/.default=1
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[myarr] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[draw, anchor=west]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
    \draw[myarr=.5] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[draw, anchor=west]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea. But in my case, the arrow is deep into the code, so I would really like to restrict the change *just* to the arrow definition. I'll edit the question accordingly, I feel I was not clear enough.

Comment: And thinking about it, that's strange. Given that the arrows **do** have the `scale` option, the `tranform shape` should percolate down to them, ...or not?

Comment: `scale` only acts on `coordinates`, not on `shapes` and `arrows` are `shapes`. See page 1054 of TikZ 3.1.4b manual **Coordinate Versus Canvas Transformations**

Comment: Yes --- but as you can see in the example, when you use `transform shape` scale **should** also work on the shapes: the  node (the square and the "A") is smaller!

Comment: Indeed, this is the very purpose of the `transform shape` option. It no longer applies transformations not only to coordinates, but also to shapes. See page 241 of the TikZ 3.1.4b manual.

Comment: And so, we can conclude that contrary to what I said, arrows are not forms for TikZ.

Comment: The `scale` option has been used in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182849. It is not an arrow key.