Are there constraints on scaling tikz pics?
I'm creating yet another document icon. I'm doing it as a pic so I can use the pic scaling to create different size versions depending on the diagram I'm using them in. It appears that some items in the pic don't necessarily scale. Here I have two different versions of my pic trying to solve the problem in different ways.
paper uses coordinates to define the location of each line of 'writing' in the icon. Each line is shortened on each end to create the lines of writing effect. As seen in the top row of icons, the shorten argument of the arrow style does not appear to be affected by the pic scaling. In the demonstration pictures, it stays a fixed 6pt.
paper2 was an attempt to forgo the coordinates creation and use a node instead with its inherent anchors to simplify the code. As seen in the bottom drawing, while the rest of the pic scaled, the node did not.
Thus the questions: What defines scalable objects in a pic? Is there a way to solve this? Should I be creating a custom shape instead?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, quotes}
    
\tikzset{
    pics/paper/.style args={#1/#2}{% #1 = number of pages (-1) to print in stack / #2 line weight
    code = {
        \begin{scope}[line width=#2,color=blue!50!black,
            arr/.style={{Round Cap[]}-{Round Cap[]}, shorten >=6pt, shorten <=6pt}
            ]
                \foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \d using {\n * 0.5}] in {#1,...,0}{
                \path ($(0,0) + (\d,\d)$)  coordinate (O);
                \fill[fill=white] ($(O) + (-2pt,-2pt)$) |- ++(1.2cm+3pt,2.5cm+4pt) -- ++(0.6cm+1pt,-0.6cm-1pt) |- cycle;
                \draw[fill=white] (O) |- ++(1.2,2.5) -- ++(0.6,-0.6) |- cycle;
                \fill (O) ++(1.2,2.5) -- ++(0.6,-0.6) -- ++(-0.6,0) -- cycle;
                }
            \coordinate (-southwest) at (O);
            \coordinate (-northwest) at ($(O) + (0,2.5cm)$);
            \coordinate (-northeast) at ($(O) + (1.8cm,2.5cm)$);
            \coordinate (-southeast) at ($(O) + (1.8cm,0)$);
                \foreach \n in {.32,.44,.56,.68,.8}{
                    \draw[arr] ($(-northwest)!\n!(-southwest)$) -- ($(-northeast)!\n!(-southeast)$);}
        \end{scope}
        }
    }
}

\tikzset{
    pics/paper2/.style args={#1/#2}{% #1 = number of pages (-1) to print in stack / #2 line weight
    code = {
        \begin{scope}[line width=#2,color=blue!50!black,
            arr/.style={{Round Cap[]}-{Round Cap[]}, shorten >=3.5mm, shorten <=3.5mm}
            ]
                \foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \d using {\n * 0.5}] in {#1,...,0}{
                \path ($(0,0) + (\d,\d)$)  coordinate (O);
                \fill[fill=white] ($(O) + (-2pt,-2pt)$) |- ++(1.2cm+3pt,2.5cm+4pt) -- ++(0.6cm+1pt,-0.6cm-1pt) |- cycle;
                \draw[fill=white] (O) |- ++(1.2,2.5) -- ++(0.6,-0.6) |- cycle;
                \fill (O) ++(1.2,2.5) -- ++(0.6,-0.6) -- ++(-0.6,0) -- cycle;
                }
            \node[minimum height=2.5cm, minimum width=1.8cm, anchor=south west] (n) at (O) {};
                \foreach \n in {.32,.44,.56,.68,.8}{
                    \draw[arr] ($(n.north west)!\n!(n.south west)$) -- ($(n.north east)!\n!(n.south east)$);}
        \end{scope}
        }
    }
}
    
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \pic[scale=1.0]   (paper) at (1,5) {paper=0/3pt};
        \pic[scale=0.5]   (paper) at (3,5) {paper=0/2pt};
        \pic[scale=0.25] (paper) at (4,5) {paper=0/1pt};
        \pic[scale=0.5] (paper2) at (1,2) {paper2=0/2pt};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Arrows-related dimensions scale in strange ways. Maybe this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506219/scaling-arrows-meta-with-tranform-shape can help?

The shorten key shouldn't be used in place of coordinate transformations. It is mich better to shift the start and end coordinates of the lines. It usually makes sense to use a value dependent on the line width as it scales only if the line width does. Instead of the Round Cap, you can use line cap=round with a shorten of .5\pgflinewiddth.

Thanks for the tips @Qrrbrbirlbel. I was puzzling on how to do what you suggested and J Leon V's answer below add a new skill to my belt.

@Rmano, thanks for pointing that out. It wasn't what I needed for this but it gives me a hint on another problem graphic I was struggling with that has arrows.

Excellent code wherever it came from, you only need to use absolute coordinates based on defined variables such as the height and width of the page of the figure you make, in your example, since shorten will always take an end point and It will move the distance you indicate since apparently the scale modifier does not affect it, I rewrote the code and added more variables to be able to control things like color and separation.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    pics/paper/.style args={#1/#2/#3/#4}{% #1 = number of pages (-1) to print in stack / #2 line weight
        code = {
            \begin{scope}[line width=#2,color=#4,
                arr/.style={{Round Cap[]}-{Round Cap[]}}
                ]
                \def\hpag{2.5cm}
                \def\wpag{1.8cm}
                \foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \d using {\n * #3}] in {#1,...,0}{
                    \path ($(0,0) + (\d,\d)$)  coordinate (O);
                    \fill[fill=white] ($(O) + (-2pt,-2pt)$) |- ++(\wpag*0.66+3pt,\hpag+4pt) -- ++(0.6cm+1pt,-0.6cm-1pt) |- cycle;
                    \draw[fill=white] (O) |- ++(\wpag*0.66,\hpag) -- ++(0.6,-0.6) |- cycle;
                    \fill (O) ++(\wpag*0.66,\hpag) -- ++(0.6,-0.6) -- ++(-0.6,0) -- cycle;
                }
                \coordinate (SW) at ($(O) + (\wpag*0.1,0)$);
                \coordinate (NW) at ($(O) + (\wpag*0.1,\hpag)$);
                \coordinate (NE) at ($(O) + (\wpag*0.9,\hpag)$);
                \coordinate (SE) at ($(O) + (\wpag*0.9,0)$);
                \foreach \n in {.32,.44,.56,.68,.8}{
                    \draw[arr] ($(NW)!\n!(SW)$) -- ($(NE)!\n!(SE)$);}
            \end{scope}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        \pic[scale=1.0]   (paper) at (1,0) {paper=5/3pt/0.2/blue!50!black};
        \pic[scale=0.5]   (paper) at (3,0) {paper=3/2pt/0.2/orange!50!black};
        \pic[scale=0.25] (paper) at (4,0) {paper=3/1pt/0.3/green!50!black};
        \pic[scale=0.5] (paper) at (5,0) {paper=2/2pt/0.5/red!50!black};
        \pic[scale=0.125] (paper) at (6,0) {paper=5/0.5pt/0.7/red!50!black};        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Appreciate the compliment on the code. Creating local variables is a new trick for me. Thanks for showing it. Your extra additions like variable spacing was a nice extra user modification I'd not thought about.
