# Why does TikZ arrow style not work in pgplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-arrows

Based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368327/how-to-fully-customize-arrow-heads-in-pgfplots), I defined my own arrow style in `TikZ` and expected it to work in `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{myarrow/.style={>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[round]}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    %axis line style={-Computer Modern Rightarrow[round]}, % works
    axis line style={myarrow} % does not work
    ]

    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When using the `myarrow` style, I obtain the default arrowhead:

[image]

And when I do not use the myarrow style but instead define the arrowhead directly, I get:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should type `\tikzset{myarrow/.style={-Computer Modern Rightarrow[round]}}` instead of `\tikzset{myarrow/.style={>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[round]}}}`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{myarrow/.style={-Computer Modern Rightarrow[round]}} %<--- edit

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={myarrow} % does work now
    ]

    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgf plot custom arrow]

Comment: For posterity: SebGlav's answer solved my immediate problem, but it lead to another one, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585226/how-to-prevent-custom-arrow-tip-for-tikz-and-pgfplots-from-changing-arrow-direct.