# How to get consistent arrow tips in TikZ and pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-arrows

I want to get consistent arrow tips for

1. Arrows in `TikZ` drawings
2. `pgfplots` axes
3. Arrows used to annotate features in plots produced with `pgfplots`

My solution works only for 1 and 3, as demonstrated by this MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% does work for tikz arrows
% does work for pgfplots annotation arrows
% does NOT work for pgfplots axes
\tikzset{myarrow/.style={>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale length=1.5]}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->,myarrow] (0,0) -- (0,3);
  \draw[<-,myarrow] (1,0) -- (1,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=4.0cm,height=4.0cm,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    xticklabels = {},yticklabels={},axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={myarrow}]
    \addplot {x^2};

    \draw[color=red   ,->,myarrow] (axis cs:0.0,0.4) -- (1.0,0.4);
    \draw[color=orange,<-,myarrow] (axis cs:0.0,0.6) -- (1.0,0.6);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

Note that the tips of the axes do not correspond to those of the other arrows. How can I define my arrow tip so it works for all three situations?

Notes:

1. In a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585176/why-does-tikz-arrow-style-not-work-in-pgplots), I asked about 2 only, and the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585182/18181) leads to arrows that do not work for 1 and 3 (which work only for `->` but not for `<-` in the sense that they always appear as `->`).
2. This is a significant reformulation of my question because it was unclear (sorry about that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a *line style* for `axis line style` e.g. an arrow with a `myarrow` tip. Like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\tikzset{
  myarrow/.style={>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale length=1.5]}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->, myarrow] (0,0) -- (0,3);
  \draw[<-, myarrow] (1,0) -- (1,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=4cm, height=4.0cm,
    xmin=0, xmax=1,
    ymin=0, ymax=1,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={->, myarrow}]
    \draw[red,->,myarrow] (0,0.4) -- (1,0.4);
    \draw[orange,<-,myarrow] (0,0.6) -- (1,0.6);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with myarrow arrows and axis]

Do not use `axis cs:`. Unless you have an old version of PGFPlots, it is default.

Answer (score 3):

Your style `myarrow` tells tikz to draw the arrow from left to right. In both of the following specifications,

```
<-,myarrow
->,myarrow
```

`myarrow` comes last and overwrites `->` or `<-`.

What you probably want is to change only the arrow tip. For this, use

```
>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale length=1.5]}
```

either in the definition of `myarrow`

```
\tikzset{myarrow/.style={>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale length=1.5]}}}
```

or globally for the whole `tikzpicture`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale length=1.5]}]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{myarrow/.style={>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale length=1.5]}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-2.0,xmax=2,
      ymin=0.0,ymax=4,
      enlargelimits=false,
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \draw[color=green ,<-        ] (axis cs:0.0,1.0) -- (1.0,1.0);
    \draw[color=red   ,<-,myarrow] (axis cs:0.0,2.0) -- (1.0,2.0);
    \draw[color=orange,->,myarrow] (axis cs:0.0,3.0) -- (1.0,3.0);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I did beforehand, and why I asked my first question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585176/why-does-tikz-arrow-style-not-work-in-pgplots). But then the definition does not work for the arrow tips in pgfplots. I realise now that my question did not make this sufficiently clear, so I will try again: I would like to have a single definition of a custom arrow tip that I can use in both TikZ and pgfplots, and in the latter in both annotations as well as axis tips.

Comment: @user1362373 Please extend your example to contain arrows in all situations that are relevant. The current example is typeset correctly ...

Comment: You are right of course, I reformulated my question. Hopefully it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find a single definition of the arrow tip that works for all three situations, but here's a work-around in which I simply define a second style:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{
  myarrow/.style={>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale length=1.5]}},
  myaxisarrow/.style={-{Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale length=1.5]}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->,myarrow] (0,0) -- (0,3);
  \draw[<-,myarrow] (1,0) -- (1,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=4.0cm,height=4.0cm,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    xticklabels = {},yticklabels={},axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={myaxisarrow}]
    \addplot {x^2};

    \draw[color=red   ,->,myarrow] (axis cs:0.0,0.4) -- (1.0,0.4);
    \draw[color=orange,<-,myarrow] (axis cs:0.0,0.6) -- (1.0,0.6);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would have preferred a single definition, but I can live with this.