# Using \footnotesize in tikz node labels

Tags: pgfplots, fontsize, strings

I have used `\footnotesize` to scale labels before and it has produced the desired results. But am having problems when I pass this as part of the label to a macro. The following MWE compiles but not if I comment out the line that redefines `\footnotesize`.

If needed, further details of `\ShowIntersection` can be found in [Intersections in PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/intersections-in-pgfplots) and `GetListMember` can be found in [Macro to access a specific member of a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21559/macro-to-access-a-specific-member-of-a-list)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Linear Axis Style/.style={
        clip=true,
        minor tick num=0,
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle, 
        x axis line style={name path global=XAxisLine},
        y axis line style={name path global=YAxisLine}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\GetListMember[2]{\StrBetween[#2,\number\numexpr#2+1]{,#1,},,}%

\newcommand*{\ShowIntersection}[3]{
\fill 
    [name intersections={of=#1 and #2, name=i, total=\t}] 
    [red, opacity=1, every node/.style={black, opacity=1}] 
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt)
        node [above left, blue] {\GetListMember{#3}{\s}}};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Linear Axis Style,
    xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.51,% Need asymmetry here due to bug in PGFplots
    ymin=-1, ymax=3,
    ]

\addplot[name path global=a, mark=none, domain=-2.5:2.5, thick] ({x},{x*x-0.5});%

\def\footnotesize{}% Why can I not comment this out?
\ShowIntersection{a}{XAxisLine}{{\footnotesize{$X_1$}},{$(A,B)$}}
\ShowIntersection{a}{YAxisLine}{{\footnotesize{$Y$}}} 

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this use either the `\normalexpandarg` setting of `xstring` (e.g. in the preamble) or write `\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\footnotesize` instead of just `\footnotsize`.

The issue is the `xstring` operation. A MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
% your macro:
\newcommand*\GetListMember[2]{\StrBetween[#2,\number\numexpr#2+1\relax]{,#1,},,}%
\GetListMember{\footnotesize A}{1}
% or just:
\StrBetween[1,2]{,\footnotesize,}{,}{,}
\end{document}
```

The definition of the `\footnotesize` macro starts with `\@setfontsize \footnotesize ...`, where `\@setfontsize` includes `\let \@currsize #1`, i.e. each font size macro stores itself as `\@currsize` (presumingly to be able to be restored later). Now `\StrBetween` expands the string twice. Apparently once when the comma separated values are read in and then again for the selected substring. Therefore you need to use `\noexpand` twice plus one, makes three times (to not expand the second `\noexpand`).

The `\normalexpandarg` (alternatively `\expandarg`) macro of `xstring` defines some internal macro in a way that these expansions are not done (`\def` instead of `\edef`).