# TiKZ Node positioning left of A but below B

Tags: tikz-pgf

Assume I have the following snippet/screenshot. How can I get `Desc2` on the same line as `Desc1`. So `Desc2` should be vertically placed below `T2` but horizontally at the same level as `Desc1` so that the descriptions are laid out on the same line.

**More in general: how to position a node horizontally relatively from node `X`, but vertically from node `Y`?**

*Preferable a solution without `calc` or matrix (free node placement)*

So I am looking something like:

```
 \node[below of=t2 left of d1] {Desc2};
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

**MWE:**

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance=2cm]
         \node[style={circle}] (t1) {T1} -- (t1) 
                  node[above left of=t1,style={circle}] (t2) {T2};
          \path[draw,->] (t1) -- (t2);
                  \node[below of=t1]  (d1) {Desc1};
            \node[below of=t2] {Desc2};
          \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use perpendicular coordinate system `at (t2|-d1)` in

```
\node at (t2|-d1) {Desc2};
```

`(t2|-d1)` means - x coordinate same as `t2` and y coordinate same as `d1`. So if `(x1,y1)` are coordinates of `t2` and `(x2,y2)` are coordinates of `d1` then `(t2|-d1)` (or equivalently `{d1-|t2)`) is equal to `(x1,y2)`. For more details, read `pgfmanual`, page 137, section 13.3.1.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance=2cm]
     \node[style={circle}] (t1) {T1} -- (t1)
              node[above left = of t1,style={circle}] (t2) {T2};
      \path[draw,->] (t1) -- (t2);
              \node[below = of t1]  (d1) {Desc1};
        \node at (t2|-d1) {Desc2};
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Aside, when you use `positioning` library, use the syntax `below = of` (not `below of =`) and so forth.