# Intersection on bent (edges) lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider

```
\documentclass[margin = 12mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[bend right = 40, name path = a] (0, 0) edge (2, 0);
    \draw[bend left = 40, name path = b] (0, -.5) edge (2, -.5);
    \path[name intersections = {of = a and b}];

    \draw[name path = c] (3.5, 0) -- (3, -.5);
    \draw[name path = d] (3.5, -.5) -- (3, 0);
    \path[name intersections = {of = c and d}];

    \fill (intersection-1) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:
[image: Two bent intersecting lines, tikz intersection not showing]

I would expect the filled circle to appear where the two curved lines first intersect. But the intersections of the two curved lines is actually not marked.

I also tried naming the bent paths after beding (`postaction = {name path = a}`), but the intersection still doesn't show up.

How can I fix this *without* using actual bezier curves (`.. controls ..`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can:

1. Name your `edge`s:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, margin = 1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending, intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[bend right = 40] (0, 0) edge[name path=a] (2, 0);
    \draw[bend left = 40] (0, -.5) edge[name path=b] (2, -.5);
    \path[name intersections={of=a and b}];
    \fill (intersection-1) circle[radius=1pt];

    \draw[name path = c] (3.5, 0) -- (3, -.5);
    \draw[name path = d] (3.5, -.5) -- (3, 0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

or

2. Use the `to` operation:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, margin = 1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending, intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[bend right = 40, name path=a] (0, 0) to (2, 0);
    \draw[bend left = 40, name path=b] (0, -.5) to (2, -.5);
    \path[name intersections={of=a and b}];
    \fill (intersection-1) circle[radius=1pt];

    \draw[name path = c] (3.5, 0) -- (3, -.5);
    \draw[name path = d] (3.5, -.5) -- (3, 0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Also possible (better?):

```latex
\draw[name path=a] (0, 0) to[bend right = 40] (2, 0);
\draw[name path=b] (0, -.5) to[bend left = 40] (2, -.5);
```

Both codes yield the same output:

[image]

Beware that `circle (1pt)` is an obsolete syntax that can [lead to problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527349/pgfplots-option-compat-newest-causes-crash-with-intersections) (see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/525870/73317), and [`pgfplots` issue number 232](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/232/)). Better use `circle[radius=1pt]` as I did above.