# PGFPlots x/yshift doesn't allow negative number?

Tags: pgfplots, spacing

---

I have been trying to shift the x axis label in the axis environment *down*. With not much success... For some reason when I enter `xlabel style={yshift=-1.5em}` the whole thing doesn't even compile and throws a `! Missing number, treated as zero.` at me. Please help.

Here is the code, please ignore the messy coordinates. They were generated by [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}   

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x=2.5cm,
y=2.5cm,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
every inner x axis line/.append style={-{Latex[scale=1.5]}},
every inner y axis line/.append style={-{Latex[scale=1.5]}},
xmin=-2,
xmax=2,
ymin=-1.5,
ymax=1.5,
xtick={-1,0,1},
ytick={-1,0,1},
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xlabel style={yshift=-1.5em},
xticklabel style={xshift={1em}},
yticklabel style={yshift={1em}},
]
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (0,0) -- (0:0.4) arc (0:60:0.4) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (0,0) -- (0:0.35) arc (0:20:0.35) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (0,0) circle (1);
\draw [line width=0.4pt,domain=0.0:2.027730435633692] plot(\x,{(-0.--0.8660254037844386*\x)/0.5});
\draw [line width=0.4pt,domain=0.0:2.027730435633692] plot(\x,{(-0.-0.*\x)/1.});
\draw [line width=0.4pt,domain=0.0:2.027730435633692] plot(\x,{(-0.--0.3420201433256687*\x)/0.9396926207859084});
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (2.0pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.10401667920577555,0.09712413496725324) node {$S$};
\draw[color=black] (-0.6287544305508752,0.958767374391877) node {$k$};
\draw [fill=black] (1,0) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.85,-0.1264857022536699) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=black] (0.5,0.8660254037844386) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.117013971395119,0.8872122264811816) node {$B[\cos{\alpha}; \sin{\alpha}]$};
\draw[color=black] (0.43,0.24) node {$\alpha$};
\draw [fill=black] (0.9396926207859084,0.3420201433256687) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.522992684288592,0.2400490757514338) node {$C[\cos{\frac{\alpha}{3}}; \sin{\frac{\alpha}{3}}]$};
\draw[color=black] (0.5450723295090882,0.09639927698213733) node {$\frac{\alpha}{3}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't sure what `\documentclass` arguments should be used for just a standalone tikz picture. That's the reason this was posted as such. If you could help me with that I would gladly fix the issue...

Comment: Good job, I'm going to erase my comments here! Another way to add the code is to enclose it within `\`\`\`latex` and `\`\`\`` (both on separate lines just before and just after the code). Then the 4-space indentation is not needed, which I find very convenient (esp. when copying and pasting several times from your document to update a question or answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. All compilation problems I've found in your code come from the use of deprecated `circle (〈r〉)` syntax. Use `circle[radius=〈r〉]` instead and it works.

The *x* label is placed as you appear to desire. Another possibility would be to use `xlabel style={anchor=north}`. You can also combine both `anchor` and `yshift` for fine tuning, or use `inner sep` or `inner ysep` as in `xlabel style={anchor=north, inner sep=1ex}`.

For more details, see [PGF issue 232](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/232/) (also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527349/pgfplots-option-compat-newest-causes-crash-with-intersections) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525870/drawing-circles-within-an-axis-of-pgfplots)).

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    x=2.5cm,
    y=2.5cm,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    every inner x axis line/.append style={-{Latex[scale=1.5]}},
    every inner y axis line/.append style={-{Latex[scale=1.5]}},
    xmin=-2,
    xmax=2,
    ymin=-1.5,
    ymax=1.5,
    xtick={-1,0,1},
    ytick={-1,0,1},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel style={yshift=-1.5em},
    xticklabel style={xshift={1em}},
    yticklabel style={yshift={1em}},
    ]
    \draw [line width=0.4pt] (0,0) -- (0:0.4) arc (0:60:0.4) -- cycle;
    \draw [line width=0.4pt] (0,0) -- (0:0.35) arc (0:20:0.35) -- cycle;
    \draw [line width=0.4pt] (0,0) circle[radius=2.5cm];
    \draw [line width=0.4pt,domain=0.0:2.027730435633692] plot(\x,{(-0.--0.8660254037844386*\x)/0.5});
    \draw [line width=0.4pt,domain=0.0:2.027730435633692] plot(\x,{(-0.-0.*\x)/1.});
    \draw [line width=0.4pt,domain=0.0:2.027730435633692] plot(\x,{(-0.--0.3420201433256687*\x)/0.9396926207859084});
    \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle[radius=2.0pt];
    \draw[color=black] (-0.10401667920577555,0.09712413496725324) node {$S$};
    \draw[color=black] (-0.6287544305508752,0.958767374391877) node {$k$};
    \draw [fill=black] (1,0) circle[radius=2.5pt];
    \draw[color=black] (0.85,-0.1264857022536699) node {$A$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0.5,0.8660254037844386) circle[radius=2.5pt];
    \draw[color=black] (1.117013971395119,0.8872122264811816) node {$B[\cos{\alpha}; \sin{\alpha}]$};
    \draw[color=black] (0.43,0.24) node {$\alpha$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0.9396926207859084,0.3420201433256687) circle[radius=2.5pt];
    \draw[color=black] (1.522992684288592,0.2400490757514338) node {$C[\cos{\frac{\alpha}{3}}; \sin{\frac{\alpha}{3}}]$};
    \draw[color=black] (0.5450723295090882,0.09639927698213733) node {$\frac{\alpha}{3}$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added some precisions regarding the label positioning.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer addresses the problem of a negative `yshift` value being rejected.

Comment: @Frigo The `xlabel style={yshift=-1.5em}` in my code works quite fine. Presumably, the compilation errors made the OP *believe* that the negative `yshift` was causing trouble, while it actually wasn't. Compilation errors must always be eliminated before starting to fix problems in the resulting PDF.

Comment: I am having this negative `yshift` problem since I moved to a new machine with a fresher set of distribution packages. I found out, though, that I can work around it by prepending zero in front of the minus, e.g.: `yshift=0-75pt`.

Comment: @Frigo I can confirm that this solves the problem also in `bar shift`. E.g., `bar shift=-10pt` => `bar shift=0-10pt`. Thanks!