# what is the simplest possible way to make a tikz shape with ports?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: Crossover Mapper]

I want to create diagrams with shapes connected by lines like `circuittikz`, but the online instructions and examples confuse me.  Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

% specify tikz libraries needed
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows.meta,automata,backgrounds,calc,chains,decorations,intersections,
    math,patterns,plotmarks,positioning,shadings,shapes,trees}
% need 1.15 compatibility
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.15,
    legend style = {font = \LARGE},
}

\newcommand\CM[2]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={#2}]
        \draw (0,-0.866) -- (0,-2);
        \fill (-1,-0.866) -- (+1,-0.866) -- (0,+0.866) -- cycle;
        \draw (-1,+1) -- (0,0) -- (+1,+1);
        \draw (-2,-0.433) -- (+2,-0.433);
        \fill(0,-2) circle (0.1);       % O
        \fill(-2,-0.433) circle (0.1);  % L
        \fill(+2,-0.433) circle (0.1);  % R
        \fill(-1,+1) circle (0.1);      % I
        \fill(+1,+1) circle (0.1);      % J
    \end{scope}
}

\listfiles
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \CM{A}{(-3,-3)}                        % example shape with terminals
    \CM{B}{(+3,+3)}                        % example shape with terminals
    %\node[CM](A) at (-3,-3);              % preferred syntax
    %\node[CM](B) at (+3,+3);              % preferred syntax

    \draw (-1,-3-0.433) -- (+1,+3-0.433);  % example connecting line
    %\draw (A.J) -- (B.I);                 % preferred syntax
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want to label all the circles as ports such as O, L, R, I, J such that if I instance the shape twice with node names A and B, I can then connect them by a line as in `\draw (A.J) -- (B.I);` which would connect the named circles with lines.

I would be happy to do this with custom `tikzset` or `pgfdeclareshape`, but nothing I find online seems to fit what I want to do with simplicity and clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a `pic`. Just use `(A-J)` instead of `(A.J)` to refer to your custom “anchors,” because if you use e.g. `A.J`, Ti*k*Z will look for a shape named `A` and won't find it.

Note: you should use `circle[radius=〈length〉]` rather than the obsolete syntax `circle (〈length〉)` which can cause problems (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527349/pgfplots-option-compat-newest-causes-crash-with-intersections) and [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/232/) for instance). Since all circles in your `pic` have the same radius, I've factored it out using `every circle/.style={radius=0.1}`.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  stuff/.pic={
    \begin{scope}[every circle/.style={radius=0.1}, pic actions]
      \draw (0,-0.866) -- (0,-2);
      \fill (-1,-0.866) -- (+1,-0.866) -- (0,+0.866) -- cycle;
      \draw (-1,+1) -- (0,0) -- (+1,+1);
      \draw (-2,-0.433) -- (+2,-0.433);
      \fill (0,-2) coordinate (-O) circle;       % O
      \fill (-2,-0.433) coordinate (-L) circle;  % L
      \fill (+2,-0.433) coordinate (-R) circle;  % R
      \fill (-1,+1) coordinate (-I) circle;      % I
      \fill (+1,+1) coordinate (-J) circle;      % J
    \end{scope}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic[draw=blue, fill=blue] (A) at (-3,-3) {stuff};
  \pic (B) at (3,3) {stuff};

  \draw[red] (A-J) -- (B-I);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way, better use the syntax `circle[radius=length]` as the older syntax sometimes leads to weird problems. I'll update this in the answer when I'm back at my computer.

Comment: This is done now, using `every circle/.style={radius=0.1}` for nice factoring.

Comment: I tried the circle[radius=length] and it broke my compile.  I will try putting this new recommendation in my tikzset.

Comment: This is strange. What did you replace `length` with? The updated code has been tested too, so unless there was a silly error such as looking at the wrong output file, it should work fine.

Comment: My error.  I used the literal word "length".  The second form worked just fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would place the code of your element into a pic environment and make the coordinates of the ports accessible to the outside via `coordinate` definitions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[rotatelabels]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    new element/.pic = {
        \begin{scope}[shift={(2, 0.433)}]
            \coordinate (-center)   at (0,0);
            \draw       (0,-0.866)  -- (0,-2);
            \fill       (-1,-0.866) -- (+1,-0.866) -- (0,+0.866) -- cycle;
            \draw       (-1,+1)     -- (0,0)       -- (+1,+1);
            \draw       (-2,-0.433) -- (+2,-0.433);
            \fill       (0,-2)      coordinate(-O);
            \fill       (-2,-0.433) coordinate(-L);
            \fill       (+2,-0.433) coordinate(-R);
            \fill       (-1,+1)     coordinate(-I);
            \fill       (+1,+1)     coordinate(-J);
        \end{scope}
    }
]
    \draw (0,0) to[R=$R$, *-*] (2,0) pic (X) {new element} (X-R) to[R=$R$, *-*] ++(2,0);

    \foreach \i in {O,I,J} {
        \draw (X-\i) to[R=$R$, *-*] ($(\tikztostart)!-2cm!(X-center)$);
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is excellent.  I learned what I needed from frougon, but you added some unexpected improvements.  Thank you.