# Placing a fully defined picture absolutely at any point inside a path picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfkeys, tikz-path, tikzset

The following example generates a rack switch with a single port.

The front oft the rack switch is defined by a path picture.

I add the port to path picture by using \node and i am placing the node via coodinates.
Unfortunately the coordinates of the port are ignored. Instead of this the port is placed at the center oft the path picture.

Is there a general approach to place a fully defined picture like, the port, absolutely at any point inside a path picture via coordinates?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shadings, shadows, shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\tikzset{
    port/.code={% style, size, label
        \draw[port/rect] (0,0) rectangle (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/port/tr});
        \draw[fill=black] (.1cm,0cm) rectangle (.9cm,.5cm);
        \draw[fill=black] (.2cm,.5cm) rectangle (.8cm,.7cm);
        \draw[fill=black] (.4cm,.7cm) rectangle (.6cm,.8cm);    
    },
    port/.cd,
    rect/.style={thin, fill=gray!20},
    tr/.initial={1cm,1.5cm},
    label/.initial={},
    /tikz/.cd,
    rack switch/.style={
        name=#1,
        fill=white, draw,
        minimum width=20cm,
        minimum height=4cm,
        path picture={
            anchor=center;
            \node(port1)[port] at (-2,2){};         
        }
    }
}   

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \node(Switch1) at (0,0) [rack switch=switch1]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal example?

Comment: Sigh, I always use \pgfdeclareshape to do this, not \tikzset.  I'm sure this has come up before, but I can't figure out how to search for it.

Comment: Somewhat related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538051/what-is-the-simplest-possible-way-to-make-a-tikz-shape-with-ports

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful tip. There I got to know the command \ pic better and was able to solve the problem.

Comment: My answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/609368/1952 draws the whole switch as a pic with nodes inside it. I think this way is easier to control the position of elements inside the `pic`.